# Geb Exception: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: geb/error/GebException

Tags: geb

IDE is Configured to use:
java: 7
geb: 0.9.1
Selenium java client and web driver: 2.35

When running the simple groovy script:

```
import geb.Browser

def browser = new Browser()
```

I get the following error:

```
Caught: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: geb/error/GebException
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: geb/error/GebException
    at dave.run(dave.groovy:12)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:120)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: geb.error.GebException
    ... 2 more
```

Everything compiles just fine and according to every document available, I should be okay.
Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Case Closed!

According to http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.gebish/geb-core/0.9.1, namely the "This artifact depends on ..." section, I needed some more dependencies.